# Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope

I just got my hands on a new (to me) scope. It is a fairly basic B&K model, analogue, 2 channel, 30 MHz. It seems to be in good shape. It was not expensive, so I don't have high expectations.

It came without probes, so I purchased some cheapo units that looked decent. See the link below for reference:

[Link to the probes I bought](https://www.amazon.ca/VinTeam-Oscilloscope-100MHz-Probes-Minigrabber/dp/B086PCW59Q?ref_=Oct_orecs_d_11853246011&pd_rd_w=yAmNg&pf_rd_p=0aa0cf32-2cd5-412f-ad4e-d438cd14fa50&pf_rd_r=RCNESWH80BA9X1ZJ62KH&pd_rd_r=762331de-a1d9-437c-9e05-4987a31f6880&pd_rd_wg=TT9Nw&pd_rd_i=B086PCW59Q)

I wonder if there is an issue with this scope. If I display a trace with a considerable vertical component, the trace seems skewed at the edges of the display but not at the center. I am wondering if this is a fault, an issue of cheap probes, and if there is an obvious fix.

To illustrate the issue, I am posting here two pictures of a 1 kHz sine wave (one with the probe at 1 Megaohm, and again with the probe at 10 Megaohm.)

Any ideas? Suggestions, advice are hugely appreciated.

[image: 1 kHz, 1M]

[image: 1 kHz, 10M]

Comment: that looks like pincushion distortion

Comment: Hook up the probe to the CAL test point which should give you a 1 kHz, 2 Vp-p squarewave. This will give you a vertical lines to inspect. Post another photo. It does look like pincushion.

Answer (score 1):

Around the CRT there are adjustments for cylindrical, focus, tilt and pincushion to line up the corners with the centre.  Good luck.  Don't make it worse.

Comment: I received some cal and test procedures for this scope which is quite remarkable because it is old and no longer supported.   I will run through them and post back.  Thank you.

Comment: The adjustment on this one is magnetic while on TV’s it can be electronic using a conditioned and rectified Vsweep to modulate Hsweep. Yes scopes in the 70’s and 80’s were remarkable analog designs. I have the schematics. If you find the barrel tuner, you’re in luck. Sniff with a tiny magnet and watch out for 2kV.

Comment: @CoolOhm How did it go?

Comment: @CoolOhm Old scopes from that era often have _far_ better service documentation available than modern scopes, so that's not at all remarkable.